# Apply function only if end of url has /amp/

Tags: permalinks, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I applied a filter to remove all theme styles, but I want this to happen only if the url ends with **/amp/**.

The code below is removing the .css styles on all pages, not filtering the term **/amp/** of the permalink.

I am using the [AMP for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) plugin, which adds **/amp/** at the end of the URL. Examplo: mysite.com/category/post-slug/amp/

```
function remove_all_theme_styles() {
if ( get_permalink($post->ID) . '/amp/' ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles->queue = array();
}
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'remove_all_theme_styles', 100);
```

They said to add, but neither is working.

```
function remove_all_theme_styles() {
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == get_permalink($post->ID) . '/amp/' ) {
```

Comment: Are you using an Amp plugin? Or is this a homegrown solution? Are you using a page endpoint? Or pages named `/amp`? Please edit your question with the needed information

Comment: The question was updated.

Comment: You need to ask this at Amp for WP support or in one of their groups/communities. 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would return `/category/post-slug/amp/` which is not the same as `get_permalink($post->ID)` which would return `https://example.com/category/post-slug/`

There are lots of ways to go about this, but one easy one that comes to mind is...

`if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/amp/' ) !== false ) {`

The `strpos()` PHP function finds the position of 2nd string within the 1st string, and returns false if it's not found.

So, that essentially searches the Request URI for the existence of '/amp/' and if it's found, then it proceeds with the rest of our function.

Comment: not sure the usage of `strpos` is 100% in place. While it is most likely good enough to 99% of sites, there must at least 1 that uses `amp` as category or page slug, and the detection will fail for it

Answer (score 0):

Add this function somewhere (Rename to something you wish)

```
function force_relative_url ($url) {
  return preg_replace ('/^(http)?s?:?\/\/[^\/]*(\/?.*)$/i', '$2', '' . $url);
}
```

Now you can:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == force_relative_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) . '/amp/' ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the plugin you're using, take a look at its `is_amp_endpoint()` function.

You may perform the test this way in another plugin on your theme's functions.php:

```
if( function_exists('is_amp_endpoint') && is_amp_endpoint() ) {
    // ... do stuff in AMP
}
```